# md subheader with md virtual repeater do not behave properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am using angular 1 and angular material aswell. I want to use md-subheader with multiples md-virtual-repeat-container within a ng-repeat. You can find the source code on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/keithra/pen/vWVbpP).

The problem right now is kind of tricky to explain. First of all you must resize the viewport so that the height is smaller than a full container.

Let's say i reach the end of 1 section. 2 section should appear and while scrolling, go to the top of the screen and replace the 1 section subheader (demo [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/subheader)). This is working properly as long as you're scrolling on the 1 section container, but as soon as your mouse reaches the 2 section container, it scrolls within it and the 1 section container still appears on the top of the screen.

Here is a [Video](https://streamable.com/7ktch) to show you. First I scroll on the top content, then i scroll on the subheader and it goes up, then I scroll in the second content and the subheader doesn't move up, which it should do. (Try scrolling in the second content in the angular demo link).

I am aware the codepen provided as another bug within it (I don't have it on my sources, but it randomly appeared on the codepen..), which looks kind of like an infinite scroll but you can use the slider on the right to scroll slowly and you'll understand what I mean. This is **not** the bug I'm trying to solve with this issue.

The html is pretty straight forward, since it's just a mock pattern to reproduce the bug I have on my app.

```
<section ng-repeat="title in vm.dataset">
  <md-subheader>{{$index + 1}} Section</md-subheader>
  <md-virtual-repeat-container>
    <p md-virtual-repeat="item in vm.dataset" md-on-demand="{{vm.onDemand}}">{{item.value}}</p>
  </md-virtual-repeat-container>
</section>
```

I believe the problem has something to do with the fact that you have to specify a height for virtual repeaters containers in order to work. This implementation would work perfectly with normal ng-repeat.

Comment: Unclear problem, this is not understandable

Comment: have you tried the codepen ?

Comment: yes and there is no issues

Comment: What kind of browser are you using ? Because on chrome latest versions there are .. I'll make screen shots to show you i guess.

Comment: I'm using latest browser of Chrome, yes it'll be better

Comment: Made a small video of it, hopes it's clearer this way.

Comment: ok now I understand, I must resize the viewport to make it smaller then the issue will appear.This is a very important and helpful tip that you **must** mention while asking so people can help you. Working on your issue.

Comment: I just figured it out right now I was about to say it. I'm going to edit the question aswell. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

There is a dynamic css adding `transform: translateY(n) !important;`

to `.md-virtual-repeat-offsetter`, `n` value depends on the scroll.

So easily the solution is to stop this behavior by adding:

```
.md-virtual-repeat-container .md-virtual-repeat-offsetter {
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0) !important;
   transform: translateY(0) !important;
}
```

Check the updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/AlaaMh/pen/QOZoqa).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This fixed the bug I wasn't looking to fix, but it's still usefull because it allowed me to understand how it works.

Comment: so could you be more specific about telling the problem, i thought that was your problem

Comment: Ok let me try to rephrase it. When i'm scrolling down without moving my mouse I want to see the content of a section scroll down till the end. Then once it's reached the end, I want the subheader of the next repeat to scroll up until the top. Once this subheader is on the top, i want to scroll within its content. And so on. Is it clear now ?